# About Mellin convolution technique

Tags: calculus, integral-transforms, mellin-transform

Recently I was studying the Mellin convolution technique to solve definite integrals. I am just wondering is the technique valid only for any definite integrals (with any range $\int^b_a$)? Or only integrals with the range $\int^\infty_0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

valid only for integral with the range 0 to infinity

Comment: Perhaps you'd care to expand on this answer?